# Indexed table from array of strings iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios4

I have array of strings

```
 NSMutableArray * nam = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ZAZ", @"London", @"Australia",@"England", @"Dallas", @"Mexico", @"Russia", nil];
```

How I can create indexed TableView from this string alphabetically??? Like in "Contacts"! Or maybe somebody know some lessons with this problem?

Comment: You can sort first your array alphabetically and then use that sorted array in table view ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit : Create [UITableView](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/) follow link. Use newArray as tableview array

Sort your NSMutableArray alphabetically like this:

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [nam sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Use this newArray as `TableViewDataSource` array for alphabetically ordered cells

Comment: ok. And how I add indexes? And how to do so by clicking on index a table jumped to section???

Comment: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-indexed-table-view.html

Simple project with index table)